# How to clone Railscast episode 170: openid with authlogic

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, github

Here is the Github link:

http://github.com/ryanb/railscasts-episodes/tree/master/episode-170/blog/app

Running:

```
git clone http://github.com/ryanb/railscasts-episodes.git
```

Gave me an empty folder with .git folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems to work fine for me. You can try downloading it from here instead.

http://github.com/ryanb/railscasts-episodes/zipball/master